# What do these Xcode 5.1 Test Navigator icons mean?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xctest

I've created some unit tests in my Xcode 5.1.1 project. I can understand that the "t" in these icons means "test":

[image]

—but what does "rT" mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do things in SenTestingKit/OCUnit/XCTest is to declare your tests in code. If you do, Xcode will discover them statically (ie. not at runtime) using the index. Once Xcode these tests are discovered, they show up in the test navigator with a "T" icon. So far so good.

Now, the SenTestingKit/OCUnit/XCTest frameworks also allow you to create tests on the fly at runtime. Some of our users make creative user of this capability, perhaps to wrap an external testing system or to create tests to represent a dynamic set of data. Xcode cannot discover these tests statically, and only find out about their existence when they are returning resutls during a test run. When discovered, they will show up in the test navigator with a "RT" icon. "RT" being short for "runtime discovered tests".

Finally. If there's anything wrong / unusual about your project that prevents indexing from completing or from properly parsing your test classes, then your tests wouldn't be statically discovered. You may still successfully build and run them, in which case Xcode would end up treating them as runtime discovered tests, and give them the "RT" icon.

Found that here:[XCode 5 Testing symbol "rT" means what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699730/xcode-5-testing-symbol-rt-means-what)

You can also check Apple's information on this:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-test_navigator/Recipe.html

Comment: Thanks. For reasons too complicated to go into I ended up re-implementing some tests in a separate Git branch. I created them via the Project Navigator rather than via the Test Navigator, which is why I think Xcode is classifying them as runtime discovered tests.

Comment: I cleared Xcode's derived data folders and lo and behold the "rT" icons magically converted to "T" icons!