# How to fix runtime discovered tests ("rT")

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xctestcase

In my project that is using Objective-C and Swift I have noticed that suddenly all tests in the Test navigator turned purple with “rT” icon:

[image]

I did some digging and I found out that they are [runtime discovered tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19849166/1757229). These tests are not discovered before you run them. Because of that I have to run all set of test when I add a new test. Code completion in the test target stopped working too. I also can't trigger a test with the little triangle icon offered inside the test class. I tried different suggestions - deleting `derived data`, deleting `xcuserdata`, cleaning the project, but still no luck. I am using the latest Xcode 7.3. Any others suggestions would be appreciated?